# How to model nested enums in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently working on the CVSS v3.1 implementation in TypeScript. Here is the [specification](https://www.first.org/cvss/v3.1/specification-document). The most interesting part for my question is probably **Table 15: Base, Temporal and Environmental Vectors**. Let's have a look at the **Environmental** metric group. Here we have the metrics Confidentiality Requirement, Integrity Requirement, etc. Each metric has possible values, e.g. Not Defined(X), High(H), Medium(M), and Low(L). I thought that's a pretty good use case for enums and records.

I looked at all examples I could find online but most examples are pretty simple and their value type is always the same. My value type depends on the key.

Here is what I currently have. I tried to keep it simple and use only two metrics.

```js
enum EnvironmentalMetric {
  ConfidentialityRequirement = 'CR',
  IntegrityRequirement = 'IR',
}

// references EnvironmentalMetric.ConfidentialityRequirement (CR)
enum ConfidentialityRequirement {
  NotDefined = 'X',
  Low = 'L',
  Medium = 'M',
  High = 'H',
}

// references EnvironmentalMetric.IntegrityRequirement (IR)
enum IntegrityRequirement {
  NotDefined = 'X',
  Low = 'L',
  Medium = 'M',
  High = 'H',
}
```

In the end I'd like to have two loops, an outer loop over all metrics and an inner loop for each metric value. So I tried to define a nested record. For every metric value I need to have some information like a textual description and a numeric value. This numeric value is required afterwards to calculate a score. So accessing this value in a type safe manner is also required.

```js
interface Information {
  text: string
  value: number
}

// can I improve this?
interface Metrics {
  text: string
  metrics:
    | Record<ConfidentialityRequirement, Information>
    | Record<IntegrityRequirement, Information>
}

const foo: Record<EnvironmentalMetric, Metrics> = {
  [EnvironmentalMetric.ConfidentialityRequirement]: {
    text: 'Confidentiality Requirement',
    metrics: {
      [ConfidentialityRequirement.NotDefined]: {
        text: 'Not Defined',
        value: 1,
      },
      [ConfidentialityRequirement.Low]: { text: 'Low', value: 1 },
      [ConfidentialityRequirement.Medium]: { text: 'Medium', value: 1 },
      [ConfidentialityRequirement.High]: { text: 'High', value: 1 },
    },
  },
  [EnvironmentalMetric.IntegrityRequirement]: {
      text: 'Integrity Requirement',
      metrics: {
          [IntegrityRequirement.NotDefined]: { text: 'Not Defined', value: 1 },
          [IntegrityRequirement.Low]: { text: 'Low', value: 1 },
          [IntegrityRequirement.Medium]: { text: 'Medium', value: 1 },
          [IntegrityRequirement.High]: { text: 'High', value: 1 },
      }
  }
}

// this should have type "Record<ConfidentialityRequirement, Information>"
// but has "Record<ConfidentialityRequirement, Information> | Record<IntegrityRequirement, Information>"
const a = better.CR.metrics

// this should have type "Record<IntegrityRequirement, Information>"
// but has "Record<ConfidentialityRequirement, Information> | Record<IntegrityRequirement, Information>"
const b = better.IR.metrics
```

My questions are:

- Can I improve my `Metrics` interface so I don't have to use the union type?
- Can I somehow make the "getters" type safe? So can I somehow say "whenever I get the value at key `EnvironmentalMetric.ConfidentialityRequirement` TypeScript knows it is of type `Record<ConfidentialityRequirement, Information>`".

I also tried using native `Map`, which works, but accessing values is quite annoying because every value can be `undefined`.

Here is a link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiBuBLATgexBUAXAhgGwFlgtlEBjKAbwCgooBhdAM0QBNtF9EsBPAJWABHMCmCYQWKAF4oAcnp9ZAGlpQAkhOABzUrwHDR4yTNlrFKgL7VqoSA2ZsOXPUJHIx2KqoByqLABFgFhBgVmk5AA1lVQAZVAB3cNkY6LoiVkQ7EwJUqAAJRC0ACyS86KsbcGgNLG1dfldDTxo6XwCgxBCwkyiVOjjEkxS+qHTM6GzcguLS8utO2uQmHDJgdRAmVGQIHCxEdC86WoAPLAAuKABnEk6tVXh8MGALqoAjYGRqCoWP5dXR4ikMiXQ5QE7nK43EB3OiYG7As6qOgAHygAjIW1YAB5GBtHBJOHhuA0DO4jEp1pttrt9iAAHxIqCo9GYrE1OrE-RuDwSCkaKk7PboBkVDEga5Qd5YRYXFnIbFwJBoDDYfBEeEU9VAy508ItKAAbUVKHQRjVgPIADpcSx2ATnCTuUYALoXfVHYCnC7yBx2vYOtGNMnYXKwi0I0F0OgGm34-1ElyknlYS1tQLBUKuyNRj1euRtKDpzqhUM5qAPPBPC4ARhGOYsdajMd9TgTjqaEktAyzlDBnohyQSynLj2eUGrUAbjOjsb9hM5QeTlrGkB7fbzshXEGHFar48njZnLftba5HZT0yKa-B3svO9HNYPjKndBfhuNyrNhHDlvZOgXSYum607rgOf71IGgEhoeUBwtqwFlmWBrgQBTrYKmfhFl0179t6BZYSWFK7mOE5voh0YoYmaGdt2bqgd6Az3pWJFPuRTaUe2wadluOEbluTF7qRME5shmj-lR56WpevEDneREPvuZFRlYr5fNYAD06lgkUiAgpcRSoGAeBhEUODwGsvAAA5rAARHK2Kzq2qHnnyGxbIKtJ0jZ1BihKODhFKizWnwlpweQlwaVpWA6XpBlGSZZkWTw1lQHZwAYvKbJifUZ5cVgrkCjSwreb5kivAFxBBWYoXhpcQA).

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can using a mapped type an a map of one enum to the other:

```
type MetricToRequirement = {
  [EnvironmentalMetric.ConfidentialityRequirement]: ConfidentialityRequirement;
  [EnvironmentalMetric.IntegrityRequirement]: IntegrityRequirement;
};

type Better = {
  [K in EnvironmentalMetric]: {
    text: string;
    metrics: Record<MetricToRequirement[K], Information>;
  };
};
```

You can liken this to a piece of (psuedo) code if it helps you understand:

```
let MetricToRequirement = {
  [EnvironmentalMetric.ConfidentialityRequirement]: ConfidentialityRequirement;
  [EnvironmentalMetric.IntegrityRequirement]: IntegrityRequirement;
};

let obj = {};

for each member of EnvironmentalMetric:
    obj[K] = {
        text: string;
        metrics: Record<MetricToRequirement[member], Information>;
    }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiBuBLATgexBUAXAhgGwFlgtlEBjKAbwCgooBhdAM0QBNtF9EsBPAJWABHMCmCYQWKAF4oAcnp9ZAGlpQAkhOABzUrwHDR4yTNlrFKgL7VqoSA2ZsOXPUJHIx2KqoByqLABFgFhBgVmk5AA1lVQAZVAB3cNkY6LoiVkQ7EwJUqAAJRC0ACyS86KsbcGgNLG1dfldDTxo6XwCgxBCwkyiVOjjEkxS+qHTM6GzcguLS8utO2uQmHDJgdRAmVGQIHCxEdC86WoAPLAAuKABnEk6tVXh8MGALqoAjYGRqCoWP5dXR4ikMiXQ5QE7nK43EB3OiYG7As6qOgAHygAjIW1YAB5GBtHBJOHhuA0DO4jEp1pttrt9iAAHxIqCo9GYrE1OrE-RuDwSCkaKk7PboBkVXgABzWRHhABVUFymhJwi0oABtOBINAYbD4KVAgB0uJY7AJzhJ3KMAF0Lob8XtTfKydgANyqNUIFDoIw6wHkPXsnScxqOiRW9a1AMuUk8rAuiwu6jitYAIWIiyVroA0lBOrB3ZqvYQfWRQ8qjsBThdrqRoS66LCi5cLizkNjdeRZQ7oyqMxa+RstoLaXTa1A4194xiQNcoO8sIsLim5x903Q3RrPdrC-CDQ5jXaiZHzdgS4zwRd5LunAeeGig9HcvX4Y3QXXVTa94TA1GjHq2oFgqEJ6vq+Z5yG0UD-p0oQPsBDx4E8FwAIwjK+FgoXWKrvleX5HhIeoDCWYLlhCyQJMoUBwQhUCIaO6GrlhJrXp2P5jJAhGgbIrEQORlHPNRtGMvRl6MThCpYHq0xFOxxHnpJPGPHxNFoYyyl0Kpqrqh6WoSN627+vUzHHhcpZ1hx+nEre37YDBj5As+JnAaq5mHmJv5+JBXTSRWYF+BBHRdPJ8GKQJjmviqzlmq5BHGUR3mkfEgVUUpdHAeFmgRpFwbiVxXkkVxiXBepoVOelBl3j+km5bJhRFAVSEhcBVhqV81gAPStWCRSICClxFKgYB4GERQ4PAayJlAABEzbYgx+6iVlfYCjSwoTdQk7Tjg4SzosBp8HqcJ2W1HVYF1PV9QNQ0jWNPASpN01sqV83RotA7LfSq3rZIrxbamHx+ntB3kJcQA)